# Script that Auto-Downloads Files From a Specified URL

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script that searches for specific MIME types on a website containing download links (.mp3, .avi, .mpeg) and want to be able to crawl that site and then download any files stored there. The pseudocode for this script:

```
Input URL
function search ()
{
    Search URL for matching MIME types and download to dir on my pc
}
```

Okay, that was really bad, but I am still learning. Would a Perl script be best for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) command. Here is an example command which will search a site recursively for all mp3, avi and mpeg files and save them into the current directory:

```
wget -r -H -nd -N -np -A.mp3,.avi,.mpeg http://www.someurl.com
```

This is what the options mean:

```
-r turns on recursive retrieving
-H Enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving.
-nd to save all files in a single directory
-N timestamping
-np Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.
-A file name suffixes to accept
```

You can also add other options for recursion depth, timeouts etc. See `man wget` for more information.

Comment: Thank you to both of you: dogbane and Kilian Foth. :) The wget command looks suitable for my purposes but I will also load the WWW:Mechanize module and explore its capabilities. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it absolutely would. Have a look at the Module [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.70/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#SYNOPSIS).